# JSF submit dataTable and openpopup window after? is this possible?

Tags: jsf, forms, datatable, submit

Is it possible to just submit a dataTable instead of the entire form and then open a popupwindow after the submit?

My dataTable has textboxes in it and the popup window is actually dependent on the data/values found in these textboxes.  Since the user can change the values of the textboxes, I am required to get the latest values from the dataTables before the popup is opened. the popup is opened through a button found in each row of the datatable.

i am using JSF2.  thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you invoke the click action, pass the id of the textarea in that row as a param then find that component in the tree and get its value. you can use that value in the popup window.

popup.xhtml:

```
<h:outputText value="#{backingBean.popupText}" />
```

in the controller:

```
public void myActionListener(ActionEvent e){

..........    
String textAreaID = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get(TEXTAREA_ID);

HtmlInputTextarea textArea = (HtmlInputTextarea)FinderUtil.findComponentInRoot(textAreaID);
String text = (String) textArea.getValue();

//this is the backing bean used in the popup window     
backingBean.setPopupText(text);

...............
}
```

Comment: ok thank you very much.  tested your code and seems to work.  i only used these:  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get(TEXTAREA_ID);  line and got the values i was looking for.  thanks!!!